# yyparse argument list: is %parse-param portable?

Tags: bison, yacc

I'm currently dealing with yacc & lex. That part is mostly done, however
I would like my yyparse function to recieve a parameter.

I found in the bison documentation this http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Parser-Function.html

Which pretty much solves my problem, however I would like to know if you guys have used

```
%parse-param  {int *nastiness}
```

Outside of Linux, I mean, do you know if %parse-param is portable? is it included in the yacc standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%parse-param` is not in [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html), and it will not work with all implementations of `yacc`. On the other hand, nothing links `bison` to Linux, and `bison` itself is quite portable.

If you are seeking portability in order to distribute source for you program, you'll likely find that many people these days do not have any `yacc` installed. It's generally easier to include the bison- and (f)lex- processed files in the tarball, and particularly if you use bison- and flex- specific features.

**EDIT**:

I just checked Berkeley yacc (`byacc`) and it does handle `%parse-param`. So it would only be AT&T yacc which doesn't, and that is not a very common installation afaik.